# Writing wstring to a pipe process with WriteFile

Tags: c++, windows

I have an application where a user can write to the Windows shell from a Linux machine and then receive the output. But when the user tries to access a directory that contains accented characters such as ("TÉST_DIR" "ÇOME_DIR"), it can not, the only way I could find it to read accented characters, was to convert the user's message to wstring, however I'm having problems to pass this conversion to the pipe input with WriteFile, for some reason it does not work, I'm probably doing something wrong.

Another method I found was putting the character encoding from the linux side terminal to cp-1252 and using SetConsoleCP / SetConsoleOutputCP with the same encoding on the windows side, however it's a solution I do not want to use because that application in the future should stay multi platform .

Below are the functions I use to receive client messages and write to the pipe input, and the function for convert a string to wstring.

Any solution to my problem?

```
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- s2ws - Convert string to wstring                              ---*/
/*---------------------------------------------------------------------*/
std::wstring Gear::s2ws(const std::string& str)
{
    using convert_typeX = std::codecvt_utf8<wchar_t>;
    std::wstring_convert<convert_typeX, wchar_t> converterX;

    return converterX.from_bytes(str);
}


/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*--- ClientSocketToShell - Read client response then write to pipe process            ---*/
/*----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
DWORD WINAPI Gear::ClientSocketToShell(LPVOID lpParameter)
{
    sThreadInfo *stI = (sThreadInfo*)lpParameter;

    BYTE buffer[4096];
    fd_set rds;
    DWORD BytesWritten;

    while (!stI->Stop) {
        FD_ZERO(&rds);
        FD_SET(stI->sockfd, &rds);

        timeval timeout;
        timeout.tv_sec = 1;
        timeout.tv_usec = 0;

        int ret = select(0, &rds, NULL, NULL, &timeout);
        if (ret < 0)
            break;

        if (ret > 0) {
            ret = SSL_read(stI->ssl, (char *)buffer, sizeof(buffer) - 1);
            if (ret <= 0)
                break;

            if (!WriteFile(stI->hStdIn, buffer, ret, &BytesWritten, NULL))
                break;
        }
    }
    return(0);
}
```

Comment: The posted code doesn't appear to do any sort of conversion; the function `s2ws` doesn't get called.

Comment: @HarryJohnston I call it right after ssl_read, but I removed because the converted wstring was not working with WriteFile(Nothing happens in the shell). I just mentioned the function to show how I am converting a string to wstring

Comment: Regarding `SetConsoleCP / SetConsoleOutputCP` ... you may try CP_UTF8 (65001)

Comment: If you do it with `wstring` I think you would need conversion in both directions. Linux UTF-8 -> Windows UTF-16 -> Linux UTF-8. Right now you have only the first part, for 2nd part you could use `wstring_convert::to_bytes()`.

Comment: can you give a example?

Comment: IMO, the most likely place for a bug is in the code you've left out.  We'll also need a description of what goes wrong, "does not work" is awfully vague.